# Material UI Raised Button change color on hover

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I need change the raised button background color on hover in Material UI.
Tried this but not working, is there a way to change the background color in the material Ui, raised button?

**Exemple.JS**

```
<RaisedButton 
        className="bouton"
        secondary={false}
        label="CONNEXION"
        fullWidth={true}
        labelPosition="before"
        icon={<img src="../../images/next.png" />}
        onTouchTap={() => signinWithEmailAndPassword(document.getElementById('Email').value, document.getElementById('password').value)}
        />
```

Exemple.css

```
    .bouton{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #00BCD4;
}

    .bouton:hover{
        background-color: #00BCD4;
        color: #FFF;
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you didn't set an image as a background you can change color width `background-color`, but you need to calculate the weight of selectors.

Next code use to check your button.

```
.button {
   position: absolute;
   bottom: 0;
   left: 0;
   background-color: #00BCD4 !important;
}

.button:hover {
   background-color: green !important;
   color: #FFF;
}
```

`!important` set max weight to selectors and this **didn't use** except for check style.

if your button change color set classes so that weight of selectors will be great as a current selector